# Javascript class chaining map library

Tags: javascript, method-chaining

I work in a project with many modules implemented in 5-6 different JavaScript files.
Function 1 callback function 2 which callback function 3 etc...

Is there a library or software that can parse all the js files, and draw a mindmap of all callbacks ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of. I don't think you'll be able to know until runtime. You could then use a javascript console to look at the stack.

`console.trace()` should be useful

- http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API#console.trace.28.29

Answer (score 0):

I found 2 tools that build UML diagrams from JS code: 
http://jsuml.org/
and 
http://code.google.com/p/jsuml2/
this might create the things you want.

You can get just get a stack trace that could ease debugging if this is the main goal of your search, you can get it here:
http://stacktracejs.com/

and another simple one here:

http://eriwen.com/javascript/js-stack-trace/

You could also use this Webkit that has functionality providing stack traces:

http://www.webkit.org/blog/1544/web-inspector-understanding-stack-traces/

Comment: thanks roman for first idea: it is an UML diagram i need, drawed by netbeans or another stuff. we are 4 developers on the project, and understanding all the architecture with an UML diagram is shorter than reading all the code

Comment: find that that may be the solution:  Code Visual to Flowchart http://www.fatesoft.com/s2f/index.htm

Comment: That might work. Please update after testing if it worked for you.